# Undefined class in Visual Code for Joomla Extension Development

Tags: joomla-3.x, visualcode

I am new to use Visual Code for Joomla development.  Watched few videos and referred https://docs.joomla.org/Visual_Studio_Code to setup the IDE.

I opened couple of PHP files and noticed few errors.  One of the most common error is 'Undefined Type...'

Example

```
Undefined type 'JViewLegacy'.intelephense(1009)
```

Why it is showing the class as Undefined?  Are there any configurations I am missing in VS?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to resolve this by creating a stubs.php and place it inside the Joomla root folder.

Steps to create stubs.php

1. Downloaded the Joomla build from github
2. Extracted in my local folder
3. Open a command prompt and navigate to joomla folder
4. Run 'php build/stubGenerator.php'

This will create a file stubs.php.  I manually copied this file to my working joomla folder.